# Undefined reference to function using Class header

Tags: c++, class, header, undefined

I've been following tutorial on how to create class using header files and came to a problem even if I did everything like in tutorial. I got Cat.h, Cat.cpp and main.cpp files. All of them are in the same folder.

Cat.h:

```
#ifndef CAT_H_
#define CAT_H_

class Cat
{
public:
    void speak();
};

#endif
```

Cat.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Cat.h"

using namespace std;

void Cat::speak()
{
    cout << "Meeeow!" << endl;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Cat.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   Cat jim;
   jim.speak();

   return 0;
}
```

When i run the program I got error: "undefined reference to `Cat::speak()'". The problem is solved  when i add line #include "Cat.cpp" to main.cpp but I dont think thats a way to go and tutorial was done without that.

Comment: How are you compiling your code?

Comment: Without knowing what build toolchain you use, only appropriate answer is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: Your description sounds like you are not compiling and linking Cat.cpp.

Comment: Im running code in VS Code along with MinGW compiler installed. I run the code using Code Runner extension (which i think manually compiles the code?) How do I compile and link Cat.cpp? I'm newbie to those stuff.

Comment: You need to modify your tasks.json to get it to build all of your sources. The documentation explains the default setting is to build only the active file and how to make the change to build all cpp files in the workspace folder: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson)

Comment: Found the solution in different thread. Because Im using Code Runner extension I had to edit line in settings.json to include whole folder instead just one .cpp file. Thanks for explaning what my problem was

Answer (score 0):

Solved. For anyone having the same problem using VS Code with Code Runner extension, I found the solution in different thread:
[Code-runner configuration for running multiple cpp classes in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59474537/code-runner-configuration-for-running-multiple-cpp-classes-in-vscode)

Comment: My comment above was a bit too slow. You don't want to make an answer that is effectively  link to an existing question. Prefer to close the question as a duplicate of the the other question.