# C++ Inheritence error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm old to coding, relatively new to C++, so bear with me. I have some very simple classes to represent chess pieces.

```
//pieces.h
class Piece {
public:
    Piece() = default;
    Piece(bool c);
    virtual const char* get_piece() const = 0;
    bool color;
};

class King : public Piece {
public:
    using Piece::Piece;
    virtual const char* get_piece() const;
};
```

```
//pieces.cpp
#include "pieces.h"
Piece::Piece(bool c) : color(c) {};

const char* King::get_piece() const {
    return color ? "♚" : "♔";
}
```

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "pieces.h"

int main() {
    King piece = new King(true);
    std::cout << piece.get_piece() << std::endl;
}
```

When I run my code, I just run into this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Piece::Piece(bool)", referenced from:
      King::King(bool) in main-268c1c.o
  "King::get_piece() const", referenced from:
      _main in main-268c1c.o
  "vtable for King", referenced from:
      King::King(bool) in main-268c1c.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The error message is vague, and upon looking through stackoverflow threads with similar errors, I couldn't find any to apply to my situation. I added the `Piece() = default;` line to my Piece class to define a default constructor, but no dice. I'm sure there is something I'm just misunderstanding about inheritance rules here.

Comment: You need to compile both of your .cpp files together, e.g. `clang++ main.cpp pieces.cpp`

Comment: If you are using VSCode remember it builds only the active file by default. The official documentation tells you that and how to modify your tasks.json to build all the source files in your folder: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac#_modifying-tasksjson)

Comment: Side note: This is a generic issue with having multiple source files and not compiling one or more of them and not related to inheritance.

Comment: This thread solved the issue for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59474537/code-runner-configuration-for-running-multiple-cpp-classes-in-vscode

Thanks for setting me on the right path!

Comment: If you have multiple source files you probably should not use code-runner. Instead use the recommended [VSCode method](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac#_modifying-tasksjson) or better yet switch to use CMake and the CMake-tools extension: [https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools)